# Images should have a maximum width when browsing Posts in profile on stackexchange

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, profile-page, images, design

Images of post on the stackexchange profile do not have a MaxiumWidth defined and are displayed in their original size while on meta the images have a maximum width of 640px.

Post on Stackexchange:
[image: Post on stackexchange]

Post on Meta:
[image: Post on Meta]